# How to inject Javascript to https sites?

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, google-chrome-devtools, code-injection

I have a project that I have to inject Javascript into websites using the browser. I mean that I go to developer tools -> console -> enter the following:

```
window.FO_DEBUG=true; 
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
b.src="//path-to-file//"
```

The issue is that I cannot inject code from my local machine for HTTPS websites.
The only way I found to do it is to inject a file from *another* HTTPS server.

Do you know any way of injecting a file from my local machine to an HTTPS server?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to inject scripts to HTTPS websites as long as the origin of these scripts is HTTPS server.

Therefore, the easiest way to do it is to create a local HTTPS server, and inject the script from this https server.

The following videos show perfectly how to do it:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTlc5Z59FpA&t=208s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbNPi2gaJpU